# Help identifying shower valve

Tags: shower, valve

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me identify the brand of my shower valve... I can't seem to find any identifying marks on either the handle, trim or valve itself. Here's a few photos:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, without a doubt, a Moen brand valve. There are numerous trim options available in many finishes. You need to go to a good specialty plumbing shop, they will have some Moen trim items in stock and should be able to order many more items.

Bring your pictures and all old trim with you.

[image]

Comment: P.S.- don't even waste your time at a "big box" store.

Answer (score 1):

this looks like an older style moen 2520 core and valve body.  however, the screw pattern (for the escutcheon) looks odd and may be of an older or different trim style.  however, the valve core should be identical and should just swap out.

Comment: Not sure who gave you a -1, you are 100% correct this is a Moen.